# spark groupby xxx and stack two rows into list of tuple / dict

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data like

[image]

#### In pandas

to list of tuple

```py
b = df.toPandas() 
b.groupby(['product_id','store_id']).apply(lambda df:df.assign(date=lambda x:x.date.apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y%m%d') ) )[['date', 'yhat']].values)
```

[image]

to dict :

```
b.groupby(['product_id','store_id']).apply(lambda df:dict(df.assign(date=lambda x:x.date.apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y%m%d') ) )[['date', 'yhat']].values) )
```

[image]

### My Purpose

I don't tend to use pandas_udf, is there any way to do such thing just by spark ??

Comment: I highly recommend including a piece of code that we can use to create a `df` and apply different approaches quickly, rather than re-creating `df` ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :

use `create_map` + `map_concat`

```py
date_cols = df.select(F.date_format('date', 'yyyyMMdd')).dropDuplicates().toPandas().values.ravel().tolist()

df.withColumn('date', F.date_format('date', 'yyyyMMdd'))\
 .withColumn( 'date_map' , F.create_map('date', 'yhat').alias("map"))\
.groupby(['product_id','store_id']).pivot('date').agg(F.first('date_map'))\
.select('product_id','store_id', F.map_concat(date_cols).alias('date_sale_count')).show()
```

However, I doubt the efficiency of my code because date_cols need collect first . Any improvement is welcome.

[image]

Comment: I would have recommend [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) + [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list). The output is not exactly the same, both work :)